# python class __mul__

Tags: python, классы, конструктор

обучаюсь на coursera.
Сейчас последняя неделя и резко все перешло в ООП.
Что было понятнее, 7 недель, объяснили что такое +, что такое -, что такое float.
А на последней неделе - резко ООП + конструктор классов.
Я честно говоря подсъехал.

Вот пример кода:

```
from sys import stdin
from copy import deepcopy


class MatrixError(BaseException):
    def __init__(self, r1, other):
        self.matrix1 = r1
        self.matrix2 = other


class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, lists):
        self.lists = deepcopy(lists)

    def __str__(self):
        strRep = ""
        amount = 0
        for lists in self.lists:
            if amount != 0:
                strRep += "\n"
            new_str = "\t".join(str(elem) for elem in lists)
            strRep += new_str
            amount += 1
        return strRep

    def size(self):
        return len(self.lists), len(self.lists[0])

    def __add__(self, other):
        if len(self.lists) == len(other.lists):
            lenght = len(self.lists[0])
            for row in self.lists:
                if len(row) != lenght:
                    raise MatrixError(self, other)
            for row2 in other.lists:
                if len(row2) != lenght:
                    raise MatrixError(self, other)
            result = []
            numbers = []
            for i in range(len(self.lists)):
                for j in range(len(self.lists[0])):
                    summa = other.lists[i][j] + self.lists[i][j]
                    numbers.append(summa)
                    if len(numbers) == len(self.lists[0]):
                        result.append(numbers)
                        numbers = []
            return Matrix(result)
        else:
            raise MatrixError(self, other)

    def __mul__(self, alpha):
        if isinstance(alpha, Matrix):
            result = []
            numbers = []
            for i in range(len(self.lists)):
                for j in range(len(self.lists[0])):
                    numbers.append(int(alpha * self.lists[i][j]))
                    if len(numbers) == len(self.lists[0]):
                        result.append(numbers)
                        numbers = []
        else:
            result = []
            numbers = []
            for i in range(len(self.lists)):
                for j in range(len(self.lists[0])):
                    numbers.append(int(self.lists[i][j] * alpha))
                    if len(numbers) == len(self.lists[0]):
                        result.append(numbers)
                        numbers = []
        return Matrix(result)

    __rmul__ = __mul__

    def transpose(self):
        t_matrix = list(zip(*self.lists))
        self.lists = t_matrix
        return Matrix(t_matrix)

    def transposed(self):
        t_matrix = list(zip(*self.lists))
        return Matrix(t_matrix)

# Task 2 check 3
m = Matrix([[1, 1, 0], [0, 2, 10], [10, 15, 30]])
alpha = 15
print(m * alpha)
print(alpha * m)
#exec(stdin.read())
```

Он правильно отрабатывает последние выражения(при этом вывод соответствует требованиям coursera).
Но, ругается и не пропускает. Пишет - runtime error.
Как правило, такая ошибка возникает из-за косяков в цикле.
Пробовал убрать проверку

```
if instanse(alpha, Matrix)
```

-не помогло.
Я их не вижу в упор. ну предельно же просто.

На всякий случай, прошедшие тесты:

```
Тест 1
Входные данные:
# Task 2 check 1
m = Matrix([[10, 10], [0, 0], [1, 1]])
print(m.size())

Вывод программы:
(3, 2)



Тест 2
Входные данные:
# Task 2 check 2
m1 = Matrix([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
m2 = Matrix([[0, 1, 0], [20, 0, -1], [-1, -2, 0]])
print(m1 + m2)

Вывод программы:
1   1   0
20  1   -1
-1  -2  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неправильно умножаете матрицу на матрицу. Посмотрите на ютубе урок на эту тему. У вас вообще одинаковый код для умножения матрицы на число и матрицы на матрицу.

Я решил вашу задачу по своему, постаравшись написать pytonic код (с использованием фич языка) с минимумом дублирования в ущерб производительности.

Проверки и обработки ошибок не стал добавлять, чтобы не загромождать решение, только суть. Как минимум надо добавить проверки соответствия размеров матриц: для сложения и вычитания матрицы должны быть одинакового размера, для умножения количество столбцов матрицы **m** должно совпадать с количеством строк матрицы **n**. Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте.

```
import operator

class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst 

    def __str__(self):
        lst_of_strs = ['\t'.join(map(str, row)) for row in self.lst]
        return '\n'.join(lst_of_strs)

    def size(self):
        return len(self.lst), len(self.lst[0]) 

    def operation_on_pairs(self, operand_2, op):
        if self.size() == operand_2.size():
            return [[op(a, b) for a, b in zip(row_1, row_2)] for row_1, row_2 in zip(self.lst, operand_2.lst)]

    def __add__(self, operand_2):
        return Matrix(self.operation_on_pairs(operand_2, operator.add))

    def __sub__(self, operand_2):
        return Matrix(self.operation_on_pairs(operand_2, operator.sub))

    def __mul__(self, operand_2):
        def mul(row, col):
            return sum(a * b for a, b in zip(row, col))

        res_mtrx = Matrix([])
        for row in self.lst:
            if isinstance(operand_2, int):
                res_mtrx.lst.append([col * operand_2 for col in row])
            else:
                res_mtrx.lst.append([mul(row, col) for col in zip(*operand_2.lst)])
        return res_mtrx

    __rmul__ = __mul__

    def _transpose(self):
        return list(zip(*self.lst))

    def transpose(self):
        self.lst = self._transpose()

    def transposed(self):
        return Matrix(self._transpose())
```

**Тестирование**

```
m = [
        [1, 1, 0],
        [0, 2, 10],
        [10, 15, 30]
    ]
n = [
        [2, 1, 2],
        [3, 2, 5],
        [10, 15, 30]
    ]

m = Matrix(m)
n = Matrix(n)

print("{:#^50}".format("Оригинальные матрицы m и n"))
print(m, end="\n\n")
print(n, end="\n\n")

print("{:#^50}".format("Результат умножения матриц m и n"))
print(m * n, end="\n\n")

print("{:#^50}".format("Результат сложения матриц m и n"))
print(m + n, end="\n\n")

print("{:#^50}".format("Транспонированная матрица m"))
print(m.transposed(), end="\n\n")
```

**Output**

```
############Оригинальные матрицы m и n############
1   1   0
0   2   10
10  15  30

2   1   2
3   2   5
10  15  30

#########Результат умножения матриц m и n#########
5   3   7
106 154 310
365 490 995

#########Результат сложения матриц m и n##########
3   2   2
3   4   15
20  30  60

###########Транспонированная матрица m############
1   0   10
1   2   15
0   10  30
```

Comment: В ближайшее время проверю, а пока что уже ловлю в PyCharm'e слудющее:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfiledirecory*", line 50, in <module>
    print(alpha * m)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'Matrix'

Comment: @BeerAndBear Да, у меня работает только если матрица идёт первым операндом, `int` вторым. Если наоборот, то не работает.

Comment: @BeerAndBear Добавил `__rmul__ = __mul__`, как у вас - заработало.

Comment: не буду утверждать точно, так как сам не понял, но очевидно магия.